# AngularJS - Calling ng-submit with a parameter

Tags: angularjs, passport.js

I'm working with angular and passport for user authentication; I'm trying to pass the logged-in user ID when saving a form but just can't manage to make it work.
My code is pretty simple:

```
site.jade:

div(ng-controller='sitesController')
    h1 #{user.local.email}
    form.(ng-submit="createSite(user)")
        label Site Name
        input.(type="text" ng-model="siteName")
        button.btn.btn-primary(type="submit") Save


sitesController.js

$scope.createSite = function (user) {
        console.log(user); // user = undefined
}
```

The user is always 'undefined' (in console.log), even though I'm able to show the email.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean to do it without making an additional `$http` request?

Comment: where is the connection between form and user? Snippets of code shown seem disjointed. WHat is `siteName`?

Comment: I have a model called Site with siteName and others but I think it is irrelevant at this point (?). siteController.js is the controller implementation which is referenced by the ng-controller above.

Comment: What happens when you put `user.local.email` in the `createSite` function?

Either way, if `user` is bound to your `$scope` object, you could just not worry about passing in the value from your html and instead `console.log($scope.user)` and it should/will work.

Answer (score 3):

How is your form supposed to know what `user` is? The reason why it is undefined is because you haven't defined it. Why not just do it this way?

```
site.jade:

div(ng-controller='sitesController')
    h1 #{user.local.email}
    form.(ng-submit="createSite()")
          //removed the argument from above.
        label Site Name
        input.(type="text" ng-model="siteName")
        button.btn.btn-primary(type="submit") Save


sitesController.js

$scope.createSite = function () {
        console.log($scope.siteName);
}
```

In your `$scope.createSite()` function, the value `user` was NOT the same value as it would have been OUTSIDE of the function. The reason for this is that when the value of `user` is used as an argument in a function definition, trying to call that value --  like you did in your `console.log(user)` statement --  you are essentially saying "console.log the value that is passed into this function." Please pardon me if you already know this, but in JavaScript function arguments only act as references to the values the function gets called with.

Here is a little [JSfiddle to illustrate my point](http://jsfiddle.net/xd4gtne1/).

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer. Maybe I missed something in your answer; I didn't want to over complicate my question with too much code. As I said, I'm able to print the user email (see the h1 tag).
Your code doesn't solve my problem since I need to pass the user ID to the createSite function.

Comment: Please pardon my confusion. By the time the user gets to the form, are they already logged in?